# Scale an image with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

So I want to have an image that displays on the bottom half of my screen and then animate it to a smaller scale and have it attached to the top/right.  Sorry for the crude images, but this is basically what I want:

[image: Original Placement]
[image: Final Placement]

I thought I could do this by constraining the top, right, and aspect ratio of my view then just animate the change of my aspect ratio constraint.  Unfortunately, when I do this IB screams that I don't have a proper X value for my view, and when I animate the scale I just end up with my view shrunk vertically but still full width.

I hope this makes sense and someone can help me figure out how to make this happen.

Comment: are looking into animating the big image into a small image while transitioning to a new UIViewController?

Comment: Everything but the transition.  There will be a different animation happening behind the blue square animating to bring in more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out. Lets see if I can explain it clearly for others.

Position 1 Constraints:

- Left = 0
- Right = 0
- Bottom = 0
- Top = 150

Position 2 Constraints:

- Top = 40
- Aspect Ratio Height to SuperView 0.25 (I use PureLayout so
  not sure what the generic style constraint would look like)
- Aspect
  Ratio Width to SuperView 0.25

To do my animation:

```
- (void)animateAgent
{
    self.agentTop.constant = 40.0;
    [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:@[ self.agentBottom, self.agentLeft ]];
    self.agentHeightRatio = [self.agentContainer autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionHeight toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:self.animationContainer withMultiplier:0.25];
    self.agentWidthRatio = [self.agentContainer autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:self.animationContainer withMultiplier:0.25];

    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```